# get back to login page again after click on forgot password in Blazor web assembly app

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

I have a "Blazer Web assembly" app with a login page(Component) and a Forgot Password page(Component).

When I click on the "Forgot Password" link on the Login page, instead of sending me to the "forgot password" page, it sends me back again to the login page.

Here is my code:

App.Razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
              
            <NotAuthorized>                  
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>    
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">              
            </LayoutView>     
    </NotFound>
</Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase
     <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>        
    <NavBar>
        <NavBarLeft>....

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationState { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    { 
        navBarLeftInjectableMenu.SetContent(null, false);      
        if (!(await AuthenticationState).User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
        }
    }
```

Forgot Password Page:

```
@page "/ForgotPass"
@layout AuthLayout

<div class=....
```

Login Page:

```
@layout AuthLayout
@page "/LoginX"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager


<div class="hold-transition login-page">
    <div class="login-box">   
        <button @onclick="ForgotPassword" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Forgot Password</button>
    </div>  
</div>



    @code {

        void ForgotPassword()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/ForgotPassX", true);

        }   
    }
```

AuthLayout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

HttpInterceptor:

```
private async Task InterceptBeforeSendAsync(object sender,  HttpClientInterceptorEventArgs e)
    {   
        
        var absolutePath = e.Request.RequestUri != null? e.Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath : string.Empty;

        if (!absolutePath.Contains("token") && !absolutePath.Contains("acc"))
        {
            var token = await _refreshTokenService.TryRefreshToken();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                e.Request.Headers.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you not get this error: `Sorry, there's nothing at this address.`？Your page is `/ForgotPass`,  but you are directed to `/ForgotPassX`.

Comment: No , in my code is correct, but nothing happens, no errors at all

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1/ Put `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` in your forgot password page.

2/ Create a different Layout with no Authorize required then use that for your forgot password page like `@layout AnonymousLayout`

Comment: I did that before, the same result, just for a second jump to "Forgot Password" and then back again to the "login"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you call the `OnParametersSetAsync` method every time you request, and your judgment condition is forcibly directed to the `Login` page.

You can add an extra judgment to bypass the `IsAuthenticated` check.

For example: Use the `request url` to determine whether to execute this check：

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{ 
    string currentUrl = NavigationManager.Uri;
    if (!currentUrl.Contains("ForgotPass")){
        navBarLeftInjectableMenu.SetContent(null, false);      
        if ((!(await AuthenticationState).User.Identity.IsAuthenticated))
        {
             NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Login");
        }
    }
}
```